# Set Musescore 4 chord style to jazz by default

Tags: musescore

I'm working with hundreds of jazz lead sheets in musicxml format, and when I load them into Musescore 4.1.1, the chord symbols don't load properly.  The chord types show, but not the root.  I can fix this by manually going into the menu Format > Style > Chords, and selecting the "jazz" option, however, this is time consuming, and I'd like to set things up to select this option by default. Can anyone help?

A screen capture of the problem looks like this:
[image]

I can fix this problem in Format>Style>Chords and clicking on the "jazz" option, and then my score looks like this:

[image]

Comment: I’m not familiar with Musescore so I will not answer, I’ll just comment with some general suggestions that the program may have. Maybe you can have your default song contain the jazz option or maybe you can create a key command for selecting the jazz option. Apart from that it sounds like all you have to do is select one option from a few drop down menus, how time consuming is that? Also what’s with all the grace notes? :)

Comment: What do you do with hundreds of files? It sounds like you're mass-printing things or something, and so you probably already have some kind of a script running that automatically. Or if not, you should have. Add the jazz chord option thing to the script.

Comment: Thanks for these suggestions.  I looked into defining a keyboard shortcut for this, but it Musescore doesn't seem to support this particular feature in that way.  The reason I need this is because I'm working with over 300 musicxml scores that I analyze using custom Python scripts.  I then want to visualize features (and listen to them) using Musescore.  I go back and forth between dozens of scores at a time, and those few clicks add up to quite a lot of repetitive work.

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica, adding the jazz chord option in a script sounds good... do you know how to do that?  As that a tag I can add to my musicxml files?

Comment: I meant GUI automation, making a script use the MuseScore application like a robot, clicking buttons and menus etc. There are many kinds of GUI automation solutions for different languages and operating systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has been resolved in MuseScore 4.2.

Comment: Please add more detail, so others will know how to do it.

Comment: It isn't a problem in 4.2 so it just works.

Comment: Here are the details: download MuseScore 4.2, and then it works out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Click the `...` menu next to the Font heading in the properties panel, and "Save as default style for this score".

This also works for most other properties, and mirrors the **S** button in MuseScore 3.

Comment: I thought that only applied to the current score. So that also sets the default for the any score opened?

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't seem to work.  First, in the properties panel, there is no "Font" heading in my version of Musescore (4.1.1).  There is a "Save style..." in the Format menu with a corresponding "Load style..." entry.  But when I save a style and then try loading it, there is no apparent effect.

Comment: @TheKid Just to make the bottom-of-the-barrel dummy check, you selected a text element first? I don't know what else to tell you, I'm running 4.1.1 as well.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this for MU4, but it works fine in MU3.6.

1. Create an dummy score
2. Go into Format|Style|Chord Symbols
3. Select "Jazz"
4. Do "Save Style..." and save this style wherever you want
5. Go into Preferences|Import
6. Set "Use style file" field pointing to the style sheet you saved at (4).
7. Optional: close MU and reopen it.

When you import a score from midi, musicXml, ... it will have the jazz-style chords.